# Can't scale textures in Blender 2.81

Tags: texturing

I can't seem to scale textures on 2.81. I'm using the usual nodes but whenever I try to connect the UV or Generated to the Vector, scale option suddenly disappears. Anybody having this issue too? Can't work my way around it. 
[image]

[image]

Comment: It's missing the connection to vector. I load old projects and UV is connected to vector, not scale, but the moment i disconnect from vector the purple dot disappears, making it impossible to scale again :(

Comment: Does this happen even in a brand new file? Or only with old projects?

Comment: If I open an old project, it is connected to vector, and scale sliders appear, the moment I unlink it, and link it again, scale doesn't pop up again.

Comment: Any brand new file I start, same thing happens.

Comment: Looks like it could be a bug, though I'm not experiencing nothing similar. Did you tried another build? Could you show a little gif of the issue?

Comment: I'm extremely confused by your screenshot.  Why is the UV connected to the Scale input instead of the Vector input?

Comment: @Carlo Yes, uploading one now, thank you

Comment: @K.A.Buhr Because connecting it to vector made Vector disappear so I thought in 2.81 maybe you had to connect directly to scale, don't know just trying, uploading a gif now to show exactly what's going on. Even if I connect it to vector, and modify scale values, texture won't act on it.

Comment: It's as if Mapping node was not working, you change values and it won't affect texture as you can see in the gif

Comment: Does your model/object have UVs in the first place????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're hooking up your nodes wrong because you've been misled by your white stucco texture.  Its base color is a nearly solid color, so scaling only the base color -- which is what you're doing in the GIF -- will have no noticeable effect.

I grabbed the base color and roughness maps for a white stucco texture from [here](https://cgbookcase.com/textures/white-stucco-wall-02), which I think are the same ones you're using in your GIF.  I applied them to the default cube using the following node network:

[image]

Note that the Vector output of the Mapping node is connected to *both* image textures.  The Texture Coordinate output should be connected to the **Vector** input of the Mapping node, leaving the Scale unconnected so you have the sliders available.

After that, scaling should work fine:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This was it! It completely went over my head, thank you again so so much!